# UITableViewCell contentView width changes in iOS5?

Tags: uitableview, ios5

On iOS < 5.0, this code for a grouped table cell of mine:

```
NSLog(@"%f", cell.contentView.bounds.size.width);
```

returns 302.

But on iOS5, the same code returns 320 (that is, including the margin of the grouped cell layout in the width).

Is that expected behaviour?

And if so, how to I then reliable get the width of a grouped, tableview cell not including the margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this change has to do with the timing of the layout of the cell and the width of 302 is set in a viewWill* or viewDid* method when more is known about accessories, tableview style, etc.

When I ran into this I fixed it by setting the `autoresizingMask` property appropriately for when the contentView was adjusted to the with of 302 later in the code.

Since I was getting the bounds width so I could add a text field on the right side of the cell, simply adding:

```
valueTextField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

made it pop back to where it was before iOS5. I suspect I would get better behavior with this if the device was rotated or go in and out of edit mode but this particular tableview does not do either of these.

Hope this helps ya!

Comment: Good solution, but indeed where rotation is required it prevents proper autoresizing :(

Comment: That's too bad but it seems like it should help when resizing if set properly. If the cell gets wider when going to landscape and the field is to stay relative to the right side then it should move to the right properly. If it is supposed to stay where it is, relative to the left side of the cell, then checking the width is less necessary, just set the position. The only other way around it seems like it would be by manually adjusting the size or position in viewWillAppear.